# How can avoid nested subscribes with rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have rxjs nested observables, which work fine.

```
this.service.save(body).subscribe(
   () => {
       this.dialog.confirmDialog({
           title: '',
           message: 'Save okay',
           caption: 'OK'
       })
       .subscribe((yes) => {
            this.service.getGoal().subscribe(
             result => {
                 this.loading(result);
                }
              );
          });
       }
     });
```

The code does three things. First save object, secondly popup a confirmation window. Last call service to refresh the page.
I use nested subscribe here. I know it is not good in theory and I should replace them with rxjs some map function. But I just don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be roughly equivalent without nesting subscriptions:

```ts
this.service.save(body).pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => this.dialog.confirmDialog({
    title: '',
    message: 'Save okay',
    caption: 'OK'
  })),
  mergeMap(yes => this.service.getGoal())
).subscribe(result =>
  this.loading(result)
);
```

Comment: What is `mergeMap(_`? I mean underscore.

Comment: The underscore is jist a variable like any other, the code ignores it so I didn't bother with a more descriptive name. Could've use `mergMap(() =>` instead

Comment: For error handling you can use `catchError` operator in the pipe

Answer (score 0):

You should use RxJs operators to make your observable stream cleaner. Depending on your use case, some common operators include `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `map`, e.t.c.

Nesting subscribes can cause problems such as memory leaks.